# How to get running process details in Unix/Linux with java

Tags: java, linux, process, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I'm trying to get all current processes in Ubuntu with Java. I really have no idea how to get them. Please help me through this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you tried the code? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Java is cross platform, Every Java application has a single instance of class Runtime that allows the application to interface with the environment in which the application is running

So in order to get the running processes use this:

```
String processStr;
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -few");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((processStr = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(processStr); 
        }
```